# Uploading A LOT of files via JS - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I been looking for days for any sample code (without having to install or include bunch of files plugins etc) to upload files to my website (And, something that shows progress for each file).

I been trying to find just basic javascript (with/without Ajax).
I found:  https://github.com/RonnieSan/uploadify
It works, it's not perfect. The problem is I need to be able to upload 200-500 files (each less than 1 MG).
And when selecting just 50 files, it freezes.

Are there any simple already made script you guys can recommend?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: without using 3rd party tools? 'uploadify' is 3rd party tool.

use HTML input built in upload method. Link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: @Re9iNee sorry meant without having to include bunch of files ..plugins etc etc...  
ah cool didn't know firefox wrote something like this..thanks I'll check it out

Comment: Why do you care about including stuff? The Web is built on libraries. You're just going to make life very difficult for yourself if you insist on not using any

Comment: ok so I finally finished it but it's the same problem no matter which method I use.
When clicking browse, and choosing like 150 images nothing happens and after that my entire website stops working for like 10-30 min "the connection has timed out".
don't understand how am I supposed to be able to upload 500 one mb images without this problem :S

Comment: Without a [mre] of your issue we can't help very easily. But that is a _lot_ of files to be uploading via a web interface. Consider some sort of other method such as SFTP to be more efficient.